# How do I apply Cart Discount Before Tax in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have being trying to apply cart discount before tax usgin my custom Woocommerce Plugin. But it is not getting applied using the action hook **woocommerce_cart_discounts_before_tax** in my custom plugin file.

Here is the code from my custom plugin file.

```
public function custom_discount(){
                global $woocommerce;
                $abc = woocommerce_price(5);
                echo $abc;
}
```

and the action hook

```
if(!empty($_POST['apply_discount_woo'])){
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_discounts_before_tax', array(&$this,'custom_discount'));
                }
```

I get the following screen

[image]

The screenshot shows $5 above the subtotal but doesn't get applied to the cart and shows the wrong total.

Comment: From `wp-admin` --> `edit coupon` there is a check box to specify apply coupon before or after tax.

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar I'm not applying a coupon discount. I want to apply a custom discount say $5 on clickof apply Discount that you see in the screenshot.

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the value, not echo:

```
public function custom_discount(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $abc = woocommerce_price(5);
    return $abc;
}
```

However, i think this will also overwrite any other discounts that have been applied.